# Checking Google Sheets page for duplicate content in cells

Tags: google-sheets

I'm working on a conditional format to detect duplicate cell content within all rows and columns on a page.

Here's my progress:

**Range:**

```
A1:T999
```

**Custom formula:**

```
=countif(A:A,A1)>1
```

This will highlight 'Foo' if 'Foo' is present twice in one particular column. (A only.. B only... etc)

**How do I highlight 'Foo' if 'Foo' is present in *any* column. Say A, D, F, etc.**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this as a custom formula:

```
=countif($A$1:$T$999,A1)>1
```

It will give a 'circular reference' error if used as a normal formula in the sheet, but is OK in conditional formatting.

**EDIT**

I could have just put

```
=countif($A:$T,A1)>1
```